# View type intersection as object without | undefined for optional properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Example intersection:

```
interface ISelect {
    selectOnly?: boolean
}
interface IDefault {
    defaultValue: string
}

// intersection
type BothTypes = ISelect & IDefault
```

When I hover over `BothTypes` I'd like to see:

```
(alias) type BothTypes = {
    selectOnly?: boolean; // <------------ just boolean
    defaultValue: string;
}
```

#### What I've tried

With

```
type Resolve<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P]
}
type BothTypes = Resolve<ISelect & IDefault>
```

I get

```
(alias) type BothTypes = {
    selectOnly?: boolean | undefined; // <------------ | undefined added
    defaultValue: string;
}
```

I'd like to remove the `| undefined`. I tried the following but the Exclude doesn't work.

```
type Resolve<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: Exclude<T[P], undefined>
}
```

Is this even possible?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUIBsILMgbwFgAoZc5AZ21zAHkQsBPAfgC5kAjAe25zhCkAvqVCRYiFKgAiEeAFcs+YmQoATOXEVgAanCzyIHSmCigA5sNKkwTAA4oAKhBPIAvMgCiADwQGNADw8fBACyAA+yPIgGjCgEGoANFExcvFqAHzIAPTZXLz8giS2DsgA4hAg0PrAAF4QAY5ZHj5+8oGOydGx6Vk29k4uYABM7uWV1Vh1DcGFESk9VZk5ebOhRf2lAEoufABuDU1jKhTIANoACsigyADWEEzcMMiOALocrf6Hl69dqXFLDJWEibFAAIW4YAAFo4BpQxjtKPsGhgaHhkAAyNCyBRKIEgki5NBUMDALBYZDmCBgNikIklcGQmFw450vKnag4PAMZjsfIhMKRbppJYAbjZp2QsS0Sj0BiMJLMIHM4sJeSEQA)

Comment: Using your `Resolve` in  `BothTypes` insted of `selectOnly?: boolean`, use `selectOnly: boolean | undefined`

Comment: I'd like to leave `ISelect` and `IDefault` as they are. Putting `selectOnly: boolean | undefined` means user has to specify `selectOnly: undefined` instead of being able to not include which defeats the purpose.

Comment: I wrote that option in the answer as well, using `-?`

Comment: That 's the same as `Required<T>`. Not what I'm looking for.

Comment: so you want the type to be, `ISelect.selectOnly?: boolean` and not `ISelect.selectOnly?: boolean | undefined` I think `?` automatically adds undefined even if there no explicit undefined

Comment: Try using `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes so an optional prop cannot have an explicit value of `undefined`

Comment: @Woohaik sorry exactOptionalPropertyTypes is exactly what I'm looking for. My `type Resolve<T> = { [P in keyof T]: Exclude<T[P], undefined>}` compiles to correct type with this option on. Do you want to update you answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript automatically adds `undefined` to an optional property.

If you want to prevent explicit undefined in an optional property try using `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` or add `"exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true` to your `tsconfig.json` to change this behaviour.

For reference see [Exact Optional Property Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) .

With this option turned on the following works:

```
type Resolve<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P]
}
```

[Updated Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUIBsILMgbwFgAoZc5AZ21zAHkQsBPAfgC5kAjAe25zhCkAvqVCRYiFKgAiEeAFcs+YmQoATOXEVgAanCzyIHSmCigA5sNKkwTAA4oAKhBPIAvMgCiADwQGNADw8fBACyAA+yPIgGjCgEGoANFExcvFqAHzIAPTZXLz8giS2DsgA4hAg0PrAAF4QAY5ZHj5+8oGOydGx6Vk29k4uYABM7uWV1Vh1DcGFESk9VZk5ebOhRf2lAEoufABuDU1jKhTIANoACsigyADWEEzcMMiOALocjpevpKciJJsoABC3DAAAtHANKGMdpR9g0MDQ8MgAGRoWQKJQZawkXLIABy3AA7mhkOYIPhCaDKshQdwDmYQOZkHToMhgWCIQ5KGxSLiSkCQeDIcdeXlTtQcHgGMx2PkQgIANyi07IWJaJR6AxGKimCxKnF5IRAA) with `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` turned on.

Comment: Note in my practical use case (angular library) this required splitting relevant code into separate compilation module since 3rd party libraries will likely not support `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` e.g. MatMenuPanel